# How can I modify MAC Address in latest docker image tomcat

Tags: docker

Firstly, I pull the latest tomcat image from docker

```
docker pull tomcat
```

and run it

I want to modify MAC Address in the container.

But most of the methods from the Internet didn't work because the system docker image provides is debian which is simplified.

So,I wonder how to do

Comment: As fat as I know, the MAC address isn't present in the image. The virtual Ethernet adapter given to a *container* when you start it is assigned a random MAC address. If the MAC address were fixed with the image, you'd never be able to run more than one container from it. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a custom MAC address for your Tomcat container should be as simple as:

`docker run --mac-address=00:11:22:33:44:55 -p 8080:8080 -d tomcat`

You can later on check that this is the actual MAC it's using:

`docker inspect --format='{{ .NetworkSettings.MacAddress }}' $(docker ps -q -l)`